# How to know opponent's platform in quickblox app?

Tags: quickblox, quickblox-android

I m integrating quickblox to my app. (iOS & android).

I need to know opponent's platform when making call between each other.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a user's platform in custom parameters in call/accept requests

http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android#Start_Call

```
Map<String, String> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
userInfo.put("platform", "iOS");

//Start call
session.startCall(userInfo);

...

public void onReceiveNewSession(QBRTCSession session){

   // obtain received user info
   Map<String,String> userInfo = session.getUserInfo();

   String platform = userInfo.get("platform");

}
```

the same for 'Accept'
http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android#Accept_call